# how to add custom metadata to pdf using node js

Tags: node.js, pdf, aws-lambda, metadata

I am reading a pdf file from AWS s3 bucket and want to generate a new file with additional custom metadata using node in lambda.

I tried with pdf-lib NPM and was able to generate a new file but didn't find a way to add custom metadata. the NPM document only has methods to add default properties like title, author.

Please suggest any way to add custom metadata

Answer (score 1):

the best library for PDF manipulation is pdfmake

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake

you can achieve any thing from using this library.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shantanu for the answer. after a try I got to know that pdfMake library is designed for generating pdf files, does not allow editing or loading PDF files.

In my requirement PDF I already have I just want to add custom metadata to that PDF.

please suggest, thanks in advance

Comment: Give exiftool a try, it is available from the package libimage-exiftool-perl in the repositories.

Use nodeJs Shel command execution  As an example, If you have a pdf file called xyz.pdf and you want to update its metadata, Use the utility, """"exiftool""" , in this way::::::::::::::   this answer will help you https://askubuntu.com/a/39906